# asprintf function in C, what does it do?

Tags: c, linux, security, exploit, asprintf

I'm currently doing the Exploit-Exercises on level02 where in script I see a function called 'asprintf',`asprintf(&buffer, "/bin/echo %s is cool" , getenv("USER"));` buffer = null; before this function call.

Please explain to me in plain english what this function do and why it is there, I know that there is another post asking the same thing but it didn't help me that much. (and YES I read the man page!)

Please no ignore or question delete, it's not the 1st time, (message to the moderators).

Comment: Why don't you read the manpage? Is anything unclear here? https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-asprintf/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Kindly show your research effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: Read the `man` page by running `man asprintf` or reading [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html). Your question will be closed, it is off-topic

Comment: Yes I read the manpage but I don't understand how asprintf works in the syntax asprintf(&buffer, "/bin/echo %s is cool" , getenv("USER"));

Comment: Also compile your code with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Then **use the debugger `gdb`** to run your program step by step and query its state.

Comment: I'll do that thanks anyways! (you can close this topic)

Comment: Trying to understand _what_ you don't understand. Do you understand `sprintf(buffer, "/bin/echo %s is cool" , getenv("USER"));`?

Comment: no i dont understand it

Comment: Then you need to spend several days in reading about C programming and the relevant documentation

Comment: The function is doing something with the value of `buffer`. When you write the value of that variable on screen you'll see what happens to the value and it will explain itself. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much god bless you and this forum!

Comment: Then do you understand `printf("/bin/echo %s is cool" , getenv("USER")); `?

Comment: yes i do understand printf

Comment: The [manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-asprintf/) explains everything you need to know in plain english. So what's the part you don't understand?

Comment: They don't provide an example.

Comment: Here is a [simple explanation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) of `sprintf`.

Comment: why put &buffer pointer 1st in asprintf?

Comment: Because `asprintf` requires a pointer address.

Comment: why? how does it use the adress?

Comment: @MrDecode you need read the chapter dealing with pointers in your C textbook.

Comment: Ooo I get it! I read the example

Comment: @MrDecode what's your latest comment about? You probably posted it by mistake. You can delete it.

Comment: I didnt post by mistake

Comment: @MrDecode so what is it about? You just repeat the code given in the answer...

Comment: I 'pointed' you to the answer given by Michael Walz.

Comment: This topic is done like dessert and it's time to close it and appreciate how this communtiy answered in seconds! You guys are like frikin rapid response unit! helping in need!

Answer (score 1):

I think the `asprintf` function you mention is a variant of `sprintf` that is specific to the glibc standard library. The first argument to the function is not a pointer to a character array, as with `sprintf`, but a pointer to `char *` variable that will hold the address of a newly-allocated `char` array. That is, the `asprintf` function does the same as `sprintf` but, rather than working with a fixed size `char` array, it allocates space for the string that it builds. The array allocated by `asprintf` has to be freed, at some later point, by the caller.

Comment: No, `asprintf` is also POSIX, and [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has it so it is not specific to `glibc`

Comment: The Linux documentation for `asprintf` says, and I quote, "These functions are GNU extensions, not in C or POSIX." With gcc, it is necessary to define __GNU_SOURCE to get its prototype.

Comment: Sorry, it is in some TS extension [Dynamic memory extensions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic) of the C standard. But it is no more Glibc specific, even if it used to be. [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/) has it.  And the Linux documentation mentions some *BSD having it also

Answer (score 1):

Apparenty you are looking for a sample usage of `asprintf`:

```
char *buffer = NULL;
if (asprintf(&buffer, "The counter is %d\n", 42) < 0) 
  { perror("asprintf failed"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };

// now buffer points to a heap allocated string "The counter is 42\n".

printf("%s", buffer);   // print the string on the terminal

free(buffer);           // free the buffer allocated by `asprintf`.
```

Comment: But `asprintf` might fail and leave `buffer` to `NULL` (but this is unlikely). In that unlucky case the `printf` is UB

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch yes of course, but if left out error checking for brevity.

Comment: I think that for a newbie question you should check against errors. Since newbies often forgot to.

Comment: thx man! Ill try it out and read your comments until I get it!